# How to change annotation color with/without shade on iOS16

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkmapview, ios16

I have a small problem that the color of spot bubble is darker with shade after updating iOS 16. Is there any idea to return it to the flat color like the image of iOS 15.5 possibly using MKMapView. I hope there are options...

[iOS 16.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUhHc.jpg)
[iOS 15.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDCF2.jpg)

I tried writing preferredConfiguration.elevationStyle which is new parameter for iOS 16 but the appearance didn't change at all although I kind of found it.

```
    // Configure map view
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        mapView.preferredConfiguration.elevationStyle = .flat
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Comment: To my knowledge no. What you can do is giving it a .clear color and do everything yourself. You miss that nice animation if you do that and it can be some work.

Comment: Thank you, Gerd. No, I don't want to lose the bubble animation... that is the problem which gives me headache. It might be better to give up the flat color appearance and get used to new one.